# Headphone jack works in Ubuntu but not Windows?

Tags: windows, audio

I have an ASUS mobo (an M5A97 if that's relevant). The disk that came with it had RealTek audio drivers on it. When I first built my pc all was well, and the headphone jack worked as it should. After a few months, the jack would stop working. I found that I could repurpose the mic jack into a headphone jack through the magic of configuration, so all was well. I figured it was a hardware issue and that I stopped worrying about it.

Imagine my surprise of course, when I install Ubuntu and the jack works perfectly.

So the question is, Why would this happen? It worked properly at one point, but now it's like windows doesn't even realize anythings plugged in. It also hasn't gone away over several windows reinstallations.